# form submission and file upload using classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to upload  files with asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic)

I have classic asp form which has some input textboxes and dropdowns. It also has a fileupload control. all inputs are enclosed in one form I want to upload the file as well as submit the data to database. Can I do both database insertion as well as fileupload using classic asp on one button click ? How can I upload the file using classic asp. do I need to add some attribute to form element ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do both with one click, save the data to the database and upload the file. You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag.

Uploading a file is slightly trick but it is possible, you can see and example of how it's done here:

http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/viewsource.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also be warned that there is a default upload limit of 2mb, you can change that however but be sure to test with 'big-files'

Comment: True, but also note that by adding this you won't be able to read the form elements by using Request.Form as you will get gibberish - you'll have to use the upload script to read those values.